# Adding phone number to contact in IOS not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, addressbook, xcode5

I am trying to add a phone number to a iOS contact programmatically but my code isn't working.
It doesn't return any error but the contact doesn't gets updated.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
ABRecordRef person =(__bridge ABRecordRef) [[(__bridge NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBook)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CFErrorRef  anError = NULL;

ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumberMultiValue =  ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty));
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumberMultiValue, (__bridge CFTypeRef)string_number,  kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumberMultiValue, &anError);


if (anError != NULL) {   
NSLog(@"error while creating ABMutableMultiValueRef..%@", anError);  
//no error here
}
```

I can read contacts information and I am displaying it in my app.

I am using iOS 7 and Xcode 5 and I am new to iOS.

Thanks for your help. *

EDIT: I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS here:

```
[self checkForAddressBookAccess];
if(_addressBook== Nil){
   _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &anError);
}
NSArray *temp_array =(__bridge NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBook) ;
```

Comment: is there any change in code in iOS7 for adding contact?

Comment: @iAhmed I can't find anything on that subject..

Comment: have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389508/how-to-add-new-contact-to-iphone-addressbook

Comment: Do you save the address book anywhere? The changes will not stick if you don't call `ABAddressBookSave`.

Comment: Check this once

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389508/how-to-add-new-contact-to-iphone-addressbook

Comment: I have changed my code to something similar to that code but I got an error, I'll update the question with the code

Comment: @Dyna _ Did u find any solution of this issue?

Comment: Hi @Hemant, actually I didn't try it again because I had some other code to develop but if I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: addressbook is deprecated in xcode7 ios9 . just a reminder